# How to force Phing task to respect verbose exec command?

Tags: phing

In other words how to display output of currently executed `phing` task?

```
<target name="backup_db">
    <mkdir dir="${dir.sql}"/>
    <exec command="mysqldump -v -h ${db.host} -u ${db.username} -p${db.password} ${db.name} > ${dir.sql}/${dump.basename}"/>
</target>
```

This pulls a database dump, as you see I specified `-v` flag to get verbose output. Command runs successfully however with no output during the dump.

> Foo > backup_db:
>
> BUILD FINISHED
>
> Total time: 1 minute  40.81 seconds

The same command called directly in terminal will list each table one by one that's currently being dumped. How to achieve that in `phing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `passthru="true"` to the `exec` solved the problem. Now I get the output in real time.